# Can we interrupt our service if we use CI/CD

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I am a consultant for a large organization. I work with CI/CD. Now sometimes the organization actually interrupts its services for upgrading the systems - I never do that with my own apps (where I use travis-ci and google appengine). I have ten years uninterrupted service with my own app. Is it alright to name our function "continuous" when we actually interrupt our services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The 'Continuous' refers to the automation of the processes rather than zero downtime.

Having said that. I would assume that:

- If there is significant downtime they wont *want* to continuously deploy. (it would cause lots of outages)
- There is still a manual step somewhere (a fully automated process is usually fast

You can imagine a working CD setup with downtime if the downtime is very short and doesn't affect the gross functionality of the overall product